# ssas deploy issue BI 2014 version and SQL 2012 version

Tags: ssas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54S5V.png) Errors and Warnings from Response Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully. OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user myserver; 28000. Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Star DWA', Name of 'Star DWA'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Currency', Name of 'Dim Currency' was being processed. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Currency Key' attribute of the 'Dim Currency' dimension from the 'test cube' database was being processed. Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

hai to all im facing above error when im deploy the cube.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not related to cube deploy itself, it is on following processing. Seems you are doing a deploy with default VS settings when processing is combined with deploy.
Split cube deploy and processing by selecting `Do not process` in VS Project properties (Project -> Properties menu). Then deploy and on the next step - try processing. Your error will show up on processing phase. Reason is quite simple - specified datasource could not be accessed; after deployment check datasource and adjust if necessary.

Comment: Deploy the ssas project it will happen.it is sql login issue i solve it. thanks for ur responds ...............